# PNG Sequence to Sprite conversion

Tags: css, animation, sprite

Is there any readymade software that converts PNG sequence to sprite?
I know many site that do the same thing but due to NDA, we can not upload image sequence to third party sites.

Comment: So far I have found 2 options
1. Animo http://lanica.co/about/animo/
2. PS plugin https://github.com/mediochrea/SpritePlane

Anything other than this??

Comment: well i am also in search of it but as far as i know that they make use of `background-position` property to get a sprite from png sequence as a background of any div!

Comment: ImageMagick with `-append` option? http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible option (I'm not sure exactly what a "PNG sequence" is, but I think this may be applicable to your situation). https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/is-there-a-tool-to-make-a-spritesheet-out-of-1000-pngs